# onclick of sidebar item issue in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to create a simple react project. it has a navbar, sidebar and the main content area.

first a home component is displayed.

home.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "../navbar/navbar";
import Sidebar from "../sidebar/sidebar";
import "./style.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

function Home() {
  const sidebarOpen = useSelector((state) => state.sidebarOpenState);
  

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />

      <div className="home-box d-flex">
        {sidebarOpen && <div className="p-2 flex-fill"><Sidebar /></div>}
        
        
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

my navbar has a button which will change state `sidebarOpen`.

my sidebar looks like this->
sidebar.js

```
import "./style.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div className="divSidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/chess">
            <img className="sidebar-img" src="images/sidebar/chess.png"></img>
            <span className="sidebar-text">Chess</span>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/volleyball">
            <img
              className="sidebar-img"
              src="images/sidebar/volleyball.png"
            ></img>
            <span className="sidebar-text">Volleyball</span>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/football">
            <img
              className="sidebar-img"
              src="images/sidebar/football.png"
            ></img>
            <span className="sidebar-text">Football</span>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/tabletennis">
            <img
              className="sidebar-img"
              src="images/sidebar/table-tennis.png"
            ></img>
            <span className="sidebar-text">TableTennis</span>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/rugby">
            <img className="sidebar-img" src="images/sidebar/rugby.png"></img>
            <span className="sidebar-text">Rugby</span>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

when i click on `chess`, the respective component should be loaded.
chess.js

```
function Chess() {
  return (
    <>
    <h1>chess</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default Chess;
```

but the problem is my sidebar disappears. i only want the main content area to be changed nothing else. can someone help? let me know if u want to some more code.

---------edit

i have added `console.log` in two places. one is in the `navbar` where the toggle method is defined and another is in `redux store` where toggle state is defined. both the places onclick is working. i am able to see message but the sidebar is not getting rendered.

---------edit 2

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Chess from "./components/chess/chess";
import Volleyball from "./components/volleyball/volleyball";
import Football from "./components/football/football";
import TableTennis from "./components/tabletennis/tabletennis";
import Rugby from "./components/rugby/rugby";
import Home from "./components/home/home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />

        <Route
          path="/chess"
          element={
            <>
              <Navbar />
              <Chess />
            </>
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/volleyball"
          element={
            <>
              <Navbar />
              <Volleyball />
            </>
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/tabletennis"
          element={
            <>
              <Navbar />
              <TableTennis />
            </>
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/football"
          element={
            <>
              <Navbar />
              <Football />
            </>
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/rugby"
          element={
            <>
              <Navbar />
              <Rugby />
            </>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way. i rendered `<Sidebar />` again in all my child components.

like this->

chess.js

```
function Chess() {
  const sidebarOpen = useSelector((state) => state.sidebarOpenState);

return (
{sidebarOpen && (
          <div className="p-2 flex-fill">
            <Sidebar />
          </div>
        )}
)
}
```

this way when i click on button the state is updated and sidebar is rendered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Chess you navigate to "/chess"

So if u can't see your Navbar there, is because you have to render it there too.

Or, render the Navbar outside de Routes from BrowsterRouter.

We need to see the components rendering on "/chess" and the react-router-dom config on app.js (or on the top lvl you declare it)

----- edit ------

Ok, look this:

```
function App() {
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <NavBar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
}
```

If you refactor your brower like this is gona be more clean to understand the code and even easy to escale.

As u see, the navBar is outside the Routes, so its gona be visible in all routes.

then you can have this:

-> one path -> one element

your Links on navbar (or sidebar or whatelse) are gona work good.

Comment: the thing is that the navbar is getting rendered but the button for toggling sidebar doesnt work and as per your suggestion if i render navbar in chess component the Navbar is displayed twice in the page.

Comment: pls check updates in question

Comment: When you click on ches you only see "chess" on window, as a h1, right ? This is because on chess component you don't place the Sidebar. Place the sidebar also on chess component .Still need to see the app.js to see the BrowserRouter, cause this can be better-programmed.

Comment: I mean, if your "Home" compoent only holds a navbar  and sidebar, i can asume that you want to use "home" like a "header" of yor app. So then, if you place Home outside de browser you will have acces to Home into all other views (chess, futball.. etc) and you will have your app correctly working.

Comment: i have added App.js, please check and let me know what change do i make

Comment: i edited my coment. take a look and tell me.

Comment: let me check this

Comment: it didnot work but i found another way and i have added that answer. if u have suggestions on that pls let me know.